# Python webdriver: get XPATH from innerHTML

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Is there a way to get the xpath of an webelement knowing only its innerHTML value?

Say I've got a 'Save' button, which is a button with text "Save". Say that the button can change its location on the page with subsequent updates to the system, therefore changing its xpath every time.

Here is an example bit from the page source:

```
<button ng-click="Model.Save()" ng-disabled="Model.SavingChecklist" href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn" translate="">
  <span class="ng-scope">Save</span>
</button>
```

I want to search the page for the innerHTML value "Save" and return the xpath (of the second line).
Note that "Save" is not a link.

Is it possible?

Comment: what is the "second line"?

Comment: <span class="ng-scope">Save</span>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following `XPath` to match any element with `innerHTML="Save"`:

```
//*[text()="Save"]
```

or in your case:

```
//button/span[text()="Save"]
```